# Custom HttpBinding in camel-http component

Tags: apache-camel

[Camel http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) component accepts an httpBinding parameter which one can use to implement a custom HTTP binding. The funny thing is, the only non-deprecated constructor wants an instance of HttpEndpoint. How am I supposed to provide it? My understanding is that it needs the currently configured instance, which Camel should already have a reference to. The documentation for the component, of course, provides no examples...

Comment: Yes lets make this easier - I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8716

Comment: Hah, cool! Thanks a bunch, Claus!